# Ending binary pattern of SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, binary, data-recovery

I'm creating a recovery tool to recover SQLite 3 databases from a binary dump image.

The starting bit pattern and string is fine and it looks like this.

> 53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00  <<<<  SQLite format
>   3

How can I determine the end of the db file?

Comment: `xxd file.db` and look at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [file format documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html), there is no ending pattern. In particular, if the last page is a freed page or an overflow page, it can have any random content.

Assuming that the database file is not corrupt, you have to deduce its size from the [database header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header), or from the file system.

Comment: what is the offset to or location of the 'file size' in header if it is available in SQLite3 files. In my case i think i have no file systems available since this it a disk dump (shell >> dd)

Comment: Text in blue is a link, and can be clicked.

Comment: Thanks CL. It was there. the offset is 16 and the length is 2.